Asking for buffer size dimension in MPI_Bsend usage
I'm currently studying MPI library for C and I can't understand which is the best way to determine the buffer size for my MPI_Bsend to work properly. The slides which I am studying from say that the buffer which I create with MPI_Buffer_attach should always have at least a size equal to: (size of all outstanding BSENDs) + (number of intended BSENDs * MPI_BSEND_OVERHEAD). Could anyone explain to me what are those values and how I can compute them?
PS: If I allocate a buffer that is surely big enough (for example 1000000 bytes) the application works with no issues but I'd like to implement things properly.

MPI_Bsend() is evil, do not use it: there is no way to dynamically check the remaining available space of the buffer, and if your buffer turns out being too small than needed, that becomes undefined behavior and all sort of bad things can happen. But if you really want to use it, you should know the max size of your buffer, that depends on your algorithm, and allocate it based on the formula.
